# How to find out the address of Keyboard

Tags: c++, c

I am using Intel core 2 duo CPU and windows 7 OS. I heard that every device is mapped into memory, if so how can i get the address of keyboard connected to my system ? My intention is to read in keyboard input into a volatile variable. Is that possible ?

Comment: You can use scanf statement to read an data entered from standard input into an variable .

Comment: Short answer: Yes you can read keyboard input into a variable. Though the rest of your question does not make sense. 1.> Why do you want the 'address' of the keyboard's mapped memory? Are you writing an OS or a driver? Why is your variable `volatile`?

Comment: @Santhosh Pai: Yeah i can do that, but i want to know more about volatile  variable. Is it possible to read directly from address corresponds to keyboard ?

Comment: I think you're better off getting something like a Raspberry Pi and write some baremetal code for that. It has a simpler memory map and you have raw access to the peripheral interfaces.

Comment: @tangrs: Am new to programming i have no experience in programming. This doubt raised while am studying some thing regarding to volatile keyword. Sorry to say i have no idea regarding what is Raspberry Pi is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be the address of the USB controller which your keyboard is connected to. However, knowing that won't give you direct access to the keyboard, since:

1. It is a USB controller, not the keyboard itself. The keyboard sends messages to the USB controller, which in turn are interpreted by the OS into "keyboard events".
2. The OS protects hardware addresses such that you can only access them through an appropriate device driver.

In the old days, it used to not even be memory, the keyboard went to a "keyboard controller" chip, which appears at I/O port 60 and 64 (or 60/61 in the very original IBM PC and XT PC). Still, in a modern OS, you can't "peek" or "poke" the keyboard without a device driver.

Comment: Ah, `peek`! Good old days! :-)

Comment: @Mats Petersson: I just want to test a volatile variable by executing a program. Is there any way so that i can get a raw accessible address(whose content changes over the time).

Comment: @Mats Petersson: How can i get the address of USB controller ?

Comment: Unfortunately, in a modern machine, with a modern OS, it's very difficult to get to "real hardware". Even if you can find the address of the USB controller, you can't read from it's memory addresses, because they are protected by the OS. You will have to try to find another way to try out `volatile`.

Comment: How scanf()/getch() access keyboard from user program space ?

Comment: The C runtime functions that read keyboard input calls the ReadFile or ReadConsoleBuffer system calls (somewhere deep in the guts of it - there are probably half a dozen levels of C runtime library in between). These functions in turn calls the device driver functions associated with the device being read (in this case the console). And technically, if you are running a console application, it doesn't read the keyboard device anyway, it has an interface to the Windows Event system, where keyboard events are being queued in a message queue behind the scenes.

Comment: It seems things are very complicated. Please suggest me some book or something to learn these concepts.

Comment: You mean "Operating systems"? The Andrew S. Tannenbaum ones are good - explains very well from a basic level up. But that's probably not the only one - all the books I have are 20+ years old, so not really that good suggestions.

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Thank u for your time. Your information helped a lot.

Comment: Of course, you could write some code where one thread reads the keyboard input (using for example `_getch();` and stores it in a global, volatile variable, and then read that from another thread.

Comment: i will try that once i am confident with thread programming.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard is a standard input device and `scanf` can be used to read from keyboard.

Comment: What has this answer to do with actual question?

Answer (score 1):

`volatile` is being used in kernel space mostly. If you want to see this keyword in action, the easiest way would be to write a simple kernel module for Linux, which reads some random CPU peripheral register.

**UPDATE**

Even though `volatile` often is being used to read hardware registers in, for example, micro-controller firmware, it's not the only use case. After some comments below it's clear that some other real-world scenarios are possible, for example a memory-mapped file. The contents of the "memory" may change without any writes visible to the program. Without using `volatile`, a compiler could optimize reads accordingly, resulting in the wrong data being returned/processed.

Comment: Is it possible to read CPU peripheral register in Windows 
Os?

Comment: No, unless you are writing a driver. I hope you realize one simple fact that nowadays every user process is running in it's own address space, and is simply unable to access system memory?

Comment: what about Linux CPU Registers are they accessible ?

Comment: If by CPU registers you mean CPU peripheral memory, then yes, if you run your code in kernel space, i.e. kernel module.

Comment: `volatile` has plenty of legitimate non-kernel uses and no kernel programming is needed to test how the keyword works or how it alters the compiler-generated code.

Comment: @Nik Bougalis: Please suggest one such example code.

Comment: @MSharathHegde A memory-mapped file is one example that occurs to me at 6:00am. The contents of the "memory" may change without any writes visible to the program. A compiler could optimize reads accordingly, resulting in the wrong data being returned/processed.

Comment: @MSharathHegde And *most* CPU registers are *always* accessible (although it's unclear why you'd want to go that low) with no need for kernel-modules or kernel programming. Casual inspection of the generated assembly and/or machine code would prove that. If you're learning C, may I suggest you focus on learning C from a good book instead of spelunking through the system? You simply aren't well-versed enough to do so and are asking questions that don't necessarily make sense and aren't helping you learn the basics you need.

Comment: @NikBougalis: Ok, I agree, didn't think that direction. Actually I've got an idea that it would be possible to check `volatile` using two threads. Will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell about how to access the restricted memory area in MS Windows. In Linux you can use `ioperm` or `iopl` to get the I/O port privilege.

The keyboard is mapped in 0x60 the status register and 0x64 the input buffer memory locations. You can get a pretty good overview of how to read and write stuff directly from keyboard: http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev19.html

Also you might want to have a look at the Linux keyboard driver source code.

But if you have a plan to use these ports to directly read the characters typed throught the keyboard, like you do in `getchar` or `scanf` or etc. then it is not correct. Using this ports you need to write your own keyboard driver inorder to decode whatever comes through these ports and then map them into what character was pressed, take care or toggle keys and all.

Comment: So code like
const volatile char *keyBoardInput=(const volatile char *)0x60; will read in the key pressed ?

Comment: No, you need to use the `in` and `out` assembly instructions to read from port. Else you can use the `inb` and `outb` macros available in Linux.

Comment: in which header file i can find inb and outb macros ?

Comment: `sys/io.hq in Linux. Check `man inb` for the manual of the io macro family. Also check the man pages of `ioperm` and `iopl` and read how to read and interpret the read values from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know windows 7 OS, but I'm pretty sure it won't let you access the keyboard device directly, if only for security reason.